# drupal position of the form-required indicator

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-fapi

In drual 7 my forms are outputting like this

```
<label for="edit-panes-billing-billing-first-name"><span class="form-required">(*)</span> First name</label>
```

The problem being the form-required indicator goes at the front. I cannot find the hook. I need to either

I need to change the html order or wrap a span around the text part  so the output is

```
<label for="edit-panes-billing-billing-first-name"><span class="form-required">(*)</span> <span class="mytitle">First name</span></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)() to alter this field's `#required` property.

The code will be similar to:

```
$form['panes_billing_billing_first_name']['#required'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: I still want them to be required just to change the html that is output in the label. Thanks